# Hide topics for "internal use" in nodelet pipeline from external subscribers?

Tags: ros, rosbag, ros-kinetic, nodelet, nodelet-manager

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am considering to set up nodelet-based processing pipeline for pointclouds, including the nodelet-based filters described here http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros/Tutorials/filters

In order to record log data, we basically record everything currently (i.e., `rosbag record -a`).

I fear this approach will cause an (avoidable) performance overhead, as every intermediate filtering step (e.g., passthrough filtering z, then box filtering A, box filtering B, then merging the results and publishing derived information) is published and recorded externally, adding up serialization and deserialization of intermediate pointclouds, while we are actually only interested in logging the overall result of the pipeline.

Should we move towards a whitelist-based approach to log recording? Or is there a way to declare certain topics in a nodelet manager "for internal use only" and hide them from external subscribers (like `rosbag record -a`)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/334752/hide-topics-for-%22internal-use%22-in-nodelet-pipeline-from-external-subscribers?/) by [moooeeeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/27965/moooeeeep/) on ROS Answers with karma: 194 on 2019-10-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Or is there a way to declare certain topics in a nodelet manager "for internal use only" and hide them from external subscribers (like `rosbag record -a`)?

No, afaik there is no support for flagging topics as such.

`rosbag` interrogates the ROS master and asks it for all topics that are being published ([here](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/6b1ee1a43b5b0a970d85612435e269818c89a152/tools/rosbag/src/recorder.cpp#L596-L602)). The master then responds [here](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/6b1ee1a43b5b0a970d85612435e269818c89a152/tools/rosmaster/src/rosmaster/master_api.py#L821-L844).

There is nothing that makes "nodelet topics" special as far as the master is concerned (they are registered in the same way as non-nodelet topics), so it would have no way to distinguish them from the others and all appear in the list returned by the master.

> Should we move towards a whitelist-based approach to log recording?

Perhaps a blacklist would be more scalable:

> ```
> $ rosbag record --help
> ```

```
[..]
```

> ```
>   -x EXCLUDE_REGEX, --exclude=EXCLUDE_REGEX
> ```

```
                        exclude topics matching the follow regular expression
                        (subtracts from -a or regex)
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [moooeeeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/27965/moooeeeep/) on 2019-10-07**:
Thanks! I guess I will introduce an "internal_use_only" namespace to the intermediate topics and blacklist it for logging then.